# cannot select player and enemy in layer collision matrix

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision, layer

I create a new one tilemap which name is OnWayplatform, but when I want to change some thing in physics 2D I cannot select player and enemy in layer collision matrix.[image: layer collision matrix]

[image: OnWayplatform layer]

Comment: What do you mean you can't select them? They are in your picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstand how the checkboxes are ordered. The `Player` and `Enemy` checkboxes line up with the `OnWayplatform` in the first two columns.
See:
[image]

Comment: Aha...yeah, I was follow the tutorial, when I see the checkbox is different with the video so make me confose, thanks for your help.